# How to select records in mysql having multiple columns values equal to a particular set of values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables

```
games

idGame  guidUser  
-----------------
12       2        
13       3


wordstyped

idGame  guidUser  word
-------------------------
12       2        honey
12       2        apples
13       3        bread
13       3        water
14       4        foo
15       5        bar
16       2        bartender
12       4        bar
```

I want to select records in wordstyped having couples (idGame,guidUser) contained in games.

If the value to search was only one I could do

```
SELECT * FROM wordstyped WHERE guidUser IN (SELECT guidUser from games)
```

but what if the value to compare is a couple of values?

With a working query, in the example only the first 4 records of wordstyped would be selected.

Comment: Do you want to select ALL or are you asking how to get just data for  one of the games

Comment: I assume you must also have rows in the `games` table for ALL the games right?

Comment: So are you also trying to limit your results to ONLY the 2 rows `12,2` and `13,3` from the games table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you ***can*** do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM wordstyped
WHERE (idGame, guidUser) IN (
    SELECT idGame, guidUser
    FROM games
);
```

It will match `idGame, guidUser` pairs against the sub query. However, I would recommend the following which is standards compliant:

```
SELECT *
FROM wordstyped
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM games
    WHERE idGame = wordstyped.idGame AND guidUser = wordstyped.guidUser
);
```

Comment: A JOIN with an AND would also work here wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't risk that also record matching only one of the column value is selected? Like (12       4        bar)

Comment: @SashaGrievus nope, the pair must match.

Answer (score 3):

Here is join solution:

```
SELECT w.idGame, w.guidUser, w.word
FROM wordstyped w
INNER JOIN games g
    ON w.idGame = g.idGame AND w.guidUser = g.guidUser;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join and match multiple field in JOIN condition

```
SELECT wordstyped.* FROM wordstyped 
INNER JOIN games ON 
         wordstyped.guidUser = games.guidUser 
         AND games.idGame = wordstyped.idGame
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM wordstyped w
JOIN games g 
ON w.idGame=g.idGame
AND w.guidUser=g.guidUser
```

Comment: But let's not encourage `SELECT *`, eh?